# how to export correct file format from 3ds max to blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, conversion

I tried to export a 3D model from .MAX file format in 3DSMax 2013 to obj file.   when I imported the exported .obj file to blender 2.77 it dose not show/work correctly.
    **problems:**

1. in converting model was rotated 90 deg in x angle ....
2. and also some textures add in incorrect place for example boot texture add to head ....
3. and one part of model did not add to exported model in this model eyes dose not add to exported obj model ....

how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, You don't need rotate objects in 3ds. You can set Z as Up and Y as away in obj. export options. Also if you use more UVMaps, just set the right in Blender node editor. If I remember right, obj. support up to 8 UVMaps. I don't use 3ds a while, so I don't remember all terms and I can't look at export option and make screens. I answer only from my poor memory :D But maybe show you direction for solve this. Also is possible you find some tutorial, just google it :-)

Comment: ok , can you answer  the second question ?

Comment: You might try some other formats (like FBX or maybe Collada), depending on what 3DS will output.

Comment: Answer for 2nd question is in my comment: You need set correct UVMap for every texture/material in Blender. Of course you need export it. :-)